# Duplicating previous input if less than zero in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have written a python code to duplicate the previous input if any entry is `less than zero` or `nan` except the first row in a matrix. But it is not working as I need what is the possible error I am doing and is there any other efficient way to do this without using multiple `for` loops. The input matrix values may be differ in some case and may contain float values.

```
import numpy as np
from math import isnan
data = [[0, -1, 2],
        [7,8.1,-3],
        [-8,5, -1],
        ['N',7,-1]]
m, n = np.shape(data)

for i in range (1,m):
 for j in range (n):
  if data[i][j] < 0 or isnan:
   data[i][j] = data[i-1][j]

print data
```

The expected output is

```
[[0,-1,2],
 [7,8.1,2],
 [7,5,2],
 [7,7,2]]
```

But, I am getting

```
[[0, -1, 2],
 [0, -1, 2],
 [0, -1, 2],
 [0, -1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying `if data[i][j] < 0 or isnan:`. `isnan` is a function, and will always make the if statement `True`. You *would* want `isnan(data[i][j])`. But in this case, it looks like what you want to check is if `not isinstance(data[i][j], (int, float))`.

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [0, -1, 2],
    [7, 8, -3],
    [-8, 5, -1],
    ['N', 7, -1]
    ]
m, n = np.shape(data)

for i in range(1, m):
    for j in range(n):
        if data[i][j] < 0 or not isinstance(data[i][j], (int, float)):
            data[i][j] = data[i-1][j]

for row in data:
    print row
```

Output:

```
[0, -1, 2]
[7, 8, 2]
[7, 5, 2]
[7, 7, 2]
```

Comment: thank you @Cyphase..but it will not work if some other alphabet is replaced in the main data. I need something which would work for any alphabet or set of alphabet. So, I used `isnan`

Comment: @ita, what do you mean? What other alphabet? Do you mean that you want to replace anything that is not a number? If so, `isnan()` is not what you want; it only checks for the float `NaN`.

Comment: say if 'N' is replaced with some other alphabet above code won't work for that.

Comment: @ita, well sure; but your question didn't specify that it could be anything else. So is what you want basically to check if the value is not an `int` or `float`?

Comment: the entries may either be float or int

Comment: @ita, fixed, if I understood you correctly; try it now.

Comment: thank you, its working perfect. But this would take much more time if the input matrix given is huge. Is there any other efficient way to do this without multiple for loops?

Comment: @ita, I'm not sure, but you should ask another question for that; either here, or possibly on [codereview.se].

Comment: @ita, and you shouldn't worry too much about the performance until it actually starts becoming an issue for you.

Comment: I need to look into the performance as this is the pseudo code i have written. The actual table will be `14052x42` matrix

Comment: @ita, that doesn't sound too big at all. Try running the code with that data and see how it goes.

Comment: @ita, I tried it with some random data; it runs in ~0.5 seconds on my computer.

Comment: what was the shape of matrix you tried this code on?

Comment: @ita, exactly what you said, 14052x42.